# TFS Team Build Ignoring MSBuild arguments

Tags: tfsbuild

I have setup a build template (xaml) and I am trying to pass a custom argumentthrough the Team Build interface.

The build definition declares an argument:

[image]

And I am trying to pass an argument in the Team Build Dialog:

[image]

This argument never makes it into the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MsBuild Properties != Team Build Workflow Properties

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments which can be used in the Build workflow from the command line arguments?

Comment: Worth mentioning that I've defined these in the arguments tab of the activity.

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/properly-incorporate-msbuild-arguments.html